# How do I replace jQuery mouseenter with hoverintent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hoverintent

I have the following jQuery set up on a site:

```
$(function() {
 $('#sub-nav > ul > li')
    .children('a').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).siblings('ul').toggle("slow");
        return false;
    }).end()
    .children('ul').hide();
});
```

It works, but it is overly reactive, popping open any time the mouse passes over it. I would like to take the beast out a bit by using HoverIntent.

The only problem is, I am not familiar enough with hover intent to know how this would be done. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, it's just a plugin: [here.](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Where you initialize like most other plugins:

```
$("#demo3 li").hoverIntent( config )
```

Comment: so I can just swapout the .mouseenter for hoverIntent?

Comment: yes. check out the website I listed, it should explain it in more detail.